# How to use a MySQL database both remotely and locally

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, data-synchronization, multi-master

I cannot find the best solution for my problem.

I made a C++ application which runs on a Kiosk under Ubuntu that needs to store and retrieve data from a MySQL database and these same data need to be accessed from a remote web application.

These are the requirements:

- The kiosk is connected to Internet, but we cannot assume that internet is always available
- The kiosk need to always access to database because the users can access the kiosk services only after the login (user data are stored in the database)
- the remote web application needs to insert or modify data stored in the database

At the moment, I'm using a local MySQL database installed in the Kiosk with PhpMyAdmin and the application directly access the local data. Then, I used cron to upload the database once a day, then I import the database on my server in order to be accessed by the remote web application.

This is really a bad solution, so I would like to find another one.
What do you suggest?

I would like to have a database on my server and let the remote web application directly use it and receive updates from the Kiosk.

Comment: 2 MySQL servers. Master-master replication.

Comment: Is it possible to implement this by using phpmyadmin or is it a more complex procedure? On the remote database I can only use phpmyadmin and i have no chances to send commands from terminal. I have full access to my local machine.

Comment: Remote (DB, server, app, etc.) heeds in your data? Well, let them give you something - normal access to DB, at least.

Comment: I have normal access to the database, I can use everything available in phpmyadmin but I cannot execute shell commands.

Comment: *I have normal access to the database* Access via PHPMyAdmin is **NOT** normal access.

Comment: Master-master replication would be fine but I do not have access to the remote server where the MySQL server is installed. Is there any online service which allows the users to implement this kind of replication?

Answer (score 0):

Remote access can be had if you provide suitable `GRANTs` for hosts other than "localhost".